# Can't Create New Timeline from IN/OUT

Tags: davinci-resolve

I'm trying to create a new timeline from a Mark In and Mark Out segment.  I have the I/O set, I right click in the bin and select `New Timline` and `Use Selected Mark In/Out.  You can see  the settings in the snip below.  I have two minutes marked out of a 1 hour timeline.

FYI, I also removed the errant cut you see in the timeline.  That didn't resolve anything.

[image]

When I click `Create` it copies the whole 1 hour timeline.  I must be missing something really simple?